# Inconsitent decoding of image URL via 'URL.createObjectURL()'

Tags: blob, winjs

I have a WinJS app where the user can choose via a dropdown menu, to view one of several images.

During the dropdown's `onchange` event, I'm using:

```
URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: true })
```

To generate a URL which I set as a html `<img>` element's `src` property.

Whilst this works 'some' of of the time, the behaviour is very inconsistent a high proportion of the time, I get the error:

```
DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL: 'blob:7743DB87-59F8-4750-B3A2-3505518CA7CB'.
```

Obviously the blob URL varies.

This doesn't seem related to the actual image, as during testing I'm only using 3 images (all of which will load at times) but all three of them won't load at other times.

Am I using the wrong approach here? or could something else be the problem? any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, any solution greatly appreciated

Comment: @Dyna I've not found a solution but believe it's related to the memory usage of the application whilst it renders the image to screen. It seemed to me that if the image was large in terms of pixel size, the the memory needed to render it to screen in Windows apps would cause the tablet to run out of memory, this is why it was variable. Sometime the tablet would be able to do it ok and sometimes the the tablet would have memory consumed by other apps and fail.